# In TabBarViewController, how can I access my children directly?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access a child called SubscriptionsViewController (3rd tab)

This is what I'm doing, but it doesn't work.

```
var subscriptionsViewController: SubscriptionsViewController? {
    get {
        let viewControllers = self.childViewControllers
        for viewController in viewControllers  {
            if let vc = viewController as? SubscriptionsViewController {
                return vc
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: By access means you want to show that view controller?

Comment: No, I want to use that controller in my code...and call methods of that view controller

Comment: Then you should try using NSNotificationCenter or delegates depending upon your requirement.

Comment: what is `self.childViewControllers`? you can access them via `viewcontrollers` property on `UITabbarViewController`. in this case you should be using `[viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of tab bar controller, you can do it as follows:

```
var subscriptionsViewController: SubscriptionsViewController? {
get {
    let viewControllers = tabController.viewControllers //assuming you have a property tabBarController
    for viewController in viewControllers  {
        if  viewController is SubscriptionsViewController {
            return vc
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a child of your tab bar controller with the following :

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2]
```